# Python GUIについて

Tags: python, gui

PythonでGUIアプリを使いたいのですが、VB、VBAのように簡単にボタン等を配置できるようなツールを教えてください。
当方が唯一知っているのはQT Designerですが、ライセンス料が必要と聞いたので違う可能性を探りたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Python付属のTkinterではどうでしょうか。
https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.html
https://qiita.com/nnahito/items/ad1428a30738b3d93762

ためしに、ボタン配置は

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Example")
root.geometry("200x200")

def click(event):
    tm.showinfo("Hello!", "You clicked the button!")

btn = tk.Button(text="Click Me", width=25)
btn.bind("<Button-1>", click)
btn.place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

でできます。(`tkinter.messagebox`は、画面にメッセージを表示するために使います。)

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator/QtDesignerはOSS版がダウンロード、利用可能です。
「違う可能性」が主目的でないのであれば、これを利用してはどうでしょうか?